# Get the name of the Grandparent of a node

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I'm trying to transform an XML file and trying to test if a node's grandparent has a certain name but i don't know how to get to the grandparent name. this is the example I'm working on. what i tried to do is to get the parent and then find the parent of the parent but it didn't work.
thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <breakfast_menu>
    <food_XX>
    <food_X>
    <food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    </food>
    </food_X>
    </food_XX>

    <food_XX1>
    <food_X>
    <food>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    </food>
    </food_X>
    </food_XX1>
    </breakfast_menu>
```

and this is the xsl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
<xsl:for-each select=".//food">
<xsl:variable name="parentName" select="parent::food_X" />
<xsl:value-of  select="name($parentName)" />
<xsl:if test="name(parent::$parentName)='food_XX1'">
<div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
<span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/> - </span>
</div>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better, use template rules.

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//food">
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="food"/>

<xsl:template match="food_XX1/*/food">
  <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
   <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/> - </span>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Ahmed, the convention on StackOverflow is to select one of the answers that you found most helpful and click the tick-mark next to the answer to mark it as accepted. That's equivalent to saying "thank you, it worked", except it's more visible to later visitors.

Answer (score 1):

To find the parent name, you can just do this...

```
<xsl:if test="name(../..)='food_XX1'">
```

And for grandparents....

```
<xsl:if test="name(../..)='food_XX1'">
```

Note that, given your current XSLT, if the intention is just to output `food` nodes under `food_XX1` you could re-write it as this....

```
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
<xsl:for-each select=".//food_XX1/*/food">
   <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
      <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/> - </span>
   </div>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `parent::` axis selects the parent of the context node.

In your example, the context node is the `food` element being processed inside the `xsl:for-each`. `parent::food_X` is the equivalent of `./parent::food_X`

When you selected `parent::food_X`, it is attempting to select an element named `food_X` that is the parent of the context node (in this case, it is the `food` element). Then, when attempting to select the grandparent with `parent::$parentName`, was essentially saying, "give me the parent of this `food` element if it is a `food_X` element", rather than asking for the parent of `food_X`.

In order to find the parent of the `$parentName`, you need to use a step from `$parentName`, so that it looks for the parent of `$parentName`, and not the parent of the `food` element:

```
<xsl:if test="name($parentName/parent::*)='food_XX1'">
```

You could simplify your test further. Rather than selecting any parent element and then testing it's name, select the parent element `food_XXX1`:

```
<xsl:if test="$parentName/parent::food_XX1">
```

Even more simple, you could eliminate the `$parentName` variable from your XSLT and just use this:

```
<xsl:if test="parent::food_X/parent::food_XX1">
```